# paths are not defined in helper specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've just upgraded my Rails version from **4.2.6** to **5.0.0.rc1** and using RSpec version **3.5.0.beta4**.

Problem is; I have a method which calls `root_path` in my helper and paths are not defined in helper specs. Issue started after version upgrade.

I'm getting the following error when I run my helper spec;

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000002749080>:0x00000011f3e650>
```

I've tried to add following line to my helper;

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

But now error is the following;

```
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `default_url_options' for #<#<Class:0x00000001efa550>:0x0000001784ccd8>
```

How can I define path helpers for helper specs or default_url_options?

Comment: I am wrestling with this now and all the answers I've found suggest that I have to set default_url_options in environments/*.rb. However, this doesn't work at all and I'm still stumped. I'd prefer to avoid hardcoding the path I need but I'm rapidly arriving at that.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it may be a bug with RSpec, one thing you can do in your helper specs is add the necessary methods yourself.

```
describe MyHelper do
  context "doing something" do
  helper do
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    def default_url_options
      {}
    end
  end

  it "should work" do
    expect(helper.run_it).to be_truthy
  end
end
```