# Upgrade to Rails 5: Route helpers are not defined in helper specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I'm currently upgrading from rails 4.2 to rails 5.0 and managed to fix/update most of the things except a bunch of rspec tests.

When I run my suite with `rspec spec/` or `rake parallel:spec` I get intermittent test failures similar to:

[image]

Printed `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` right before the failing tests and there is no route.

This is mostly in my helpers & mailers folder. When I run the helpers with `rspec spec/helpers` they all pass. Is super strange because some helpers with route paths in them pass and some don't.

Looked at this, https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1644, `rails-controller-testing` is not the issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972278/paths-are-not-defined-in-helper-specs) did not help at all.

I'm using

- rails 5.0.7.2
- rspec-rails 3.8.2
- rails-controller-testing 1.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a lot of time on this and finally found the culprit. I started by removing folders one by one from the `specs/` folder and having `--format documentation` I managed to cut down to a single file that, when it was executed before the `helpers` in the suite, it crashed them.

That old test had

```rb
before(:each) do
  routes.draw { get 'search' => 'warden#search' }
end
```

and fixed by adding

```rb
  after do  
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
  end
```

I ended up changing the entire test eventually just to get rid if the `reload_routes!` because it seemed more of a hack than a fix.